# can't call basic websockets nodejs application

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket

Can anyone sort my life out please?

**Servside (Node.js)**

The relevant lines are:

```
var server = app.listen(process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT || 3000, function () {
console.log ('Server started on port: ' + server.address().port);
});

var wss = new WebSocketServer({
server: server,
port: 8080,
autoAcceptConnections: true
});

wss.on('connection', function (ws)
                        {
                            ws.on('message', function (message)
                                                    {
                                                        ws.send("Back");
                                                    }
                                 );

                            ws.send('something');
                        }
  );
```

I deploy my app to the cloud and it runs, Cloudfoundry tells me 1 of 1 instances running.

**Client Side**

I can browse to the app's webpage - lets say its "https://mypage.here.io" - and I see the HTML page I have made, including a button which spawns the following code:

```
function OnButton4()
{
    var bWebSocketsSupported = (("WebSocket" in window && window.WebSocket != undefined) || ("MozWebSocket" in window));

    if (bWebSocketsSupported)
    {
        var connection = new WebSocket('wss://mypage.here.io:8080');

        connection.onopen = function ()
        {
            alert("open");
        }

        connection.onclose = function ()
        {
            alert("close");
        }

        connection.onerror = function (error)
        {
            alert("Websocket Error");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alert("Websockets not supported in this browser");
    }
}
```

The problem is (you can guess!) that (after a long pause) I receive the onerror callback and then the onclose callback.

Can anyone help me with why? (also I was unable to find any useful property of the error event parameter to display. Its an object but none of the properties look informative).

Thanks,
Mitch.

Comment: Your WebSocketServer should listen on same port as your app. So your app and socket server both listen on port process.env.VCAP_APP_PORT which is port where cloudfoundry routes requests to mypage.here.io so on client use  wss://mypage.here.io

Comment: Finally back at PC after weekend and wanted to say thanks. All working now.